Surface integral generates elliptic number instead of the correct one
Compute the flux $\Phi$ of the vector field $\mathbf{F} = x \mathbf{i} + y \mathbf{j} + z \mathbf{k}$ through the portion of the ellipsoid $4x^2 + y^2 + 4z^2 = 4$ lying in the first octant using a parametric approach with parameters $u$ and $v$.
1. Parametrize the Ellipsoid
Given the ellipsoid equation:
$$
4x^2 + y^2 + 4z^2 = 4
$$
We can rewrite it in standard form:
$$
\frac{x^2}{1} + \frac{y^2}{4} + \frac{z^2}{1} = 1
$$
This represents an ellipsoid centered at the origin with semi-axis lengths:

(a = 1) along the (x)-axis,
(b = 2) along the (y)-axis,
(c = 1) along the (z)-axis.

Parametrization Using Parameters (u) and (v)
We'll use the following parametrization:
$$
\begin{cases}
x = \cos u \cos v \\
y = 2 \sin u \cos v \\
z = \sin v
\end{cases}
$$
where:

(u) and (v) are parameters that vary to cover the surface of the ellipsoid in the first octant.
To ensure (x), (y), and (z) are non-negative (since we're in the first octant), the parameters must satisfy:
$$
  0 \leq u \leq \frac{\pi}{2}, \quad 0 \leq v \leq \frac{\pi}{2}
  $$

$$
\mathbf{F}(u, v) = \left( \cos u \cos v, \, 2 \sin u \cos v, \, \sin v \right)
$$
$$
\mathbf{r}(u, v) = \left( \cos u \cos v, \, 2 \sin u \cos v, \, \sin v \right)
$$
Partial Derivatives:
$$
\mathbf{r}_u = \frac{\partial \mathbf{r}}{\partial u} = \left( -\sin u \cos v, \, 2 \cos u \cos v, \, 0 \right)
$$
$$
\mathbf{r}_v = \frac{\partial \mathbf{r}}{\partial v} = \left( -\cos u \sin v, \, -2 \sin u \sin v, \, \cos v \right)
$$
$$
d\mathbf{S} = \mathbf{r}_u \times \mathbf{r}_v \, du \, dv
$$
Cross Product Calculation:
$$
\mathbf{r}_u \times \mathbf{r}_v = \begin{vmatrix}
\mathbf{i} & \mathbf{j} & \mathbf{k} \\
-\sin u \cos v & 2 \cos u \cos v & 0 \\
-\cos u \sin v & -2 \sin u \sin v & \cos v \\
\end{vmatrix}
$$
Compute each component:
$$
(2 \cos u \cos v)(\cos v) - (0)(-2 \sin u \sin v) = 2 \cos u \cos^2 v
$$
$$
(0)(-\cos u \sin v) - (-\sin u \cos v)(\cos v) = \sin u \cos^2 v
$$
$$
(-\sin u \cos v)(-2 \sin u \sin v) - (2 \cos u \cos v)(-\cos u \sin v) = 2 \sin^2 u \cos v \sin v + 2 \cos^2 u \cos v \sin v = 2 (\sin^2 u + \cos^2 u) \cos v \sin v = 2 \cos v \sin v
$$
$$
\mathbf{r}_u \times \mathbf{r}_v = \left( 2 \cos u \cos^2 v, \, \sin u \cos^2 v, \, 2 \cos v \sin v \right)
$$
$$
\Phi = \iint_S \mathbf{F} \cdot d\mathbf{S} = \iint_D \mathbf{F}(u, v) \cdot (\mathbf{r}_u \times \mathbf{r}_v) \, du \, dv
$$
Compute the dot product:
$$
\mathbf{F} \cdot (\mathbf{r}_u \times \mathbf{r}_v) = \left( \cos u \cos v, \, 2 \sin u \cos v, \, \sin v \right) \cdot \left( 2 \cos u \cos^2 v, \, \sin u \cos^2 v, \, 2 \cos v \sin v \right)
$$
Factor out $2 \cos v$:
$$
= 2 \cos v (\cos^2 v + \sin^2 v) = 2 \cos v (1) = 2 \cos v
$$
Thus,
$$
\mathbf{F} \cdot (\mathbf{r}_u \times \mathbf{r}_v) = 2 \cos v
$$
The flux integral becomes:
$$
\Phi = \iint_D 2 \cos v \, du \, dv
$$
$$
0 \leq u \leq \frac{\pi}{2}, \quad 0 \leq v \leq \frac{\pi}{2}
$$
$$
\Phi = 2 \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \cos v \, du \, dv
$$
$$
\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} du = \left[ u \right]_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} = \frac{\pi}{2}
$$
$$
\Phi = 2 \left( \frac{\pi}{2} \right) \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \cos v \, dv = \pi \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \cos v \, dv
$$
$$
= \pi \left[ \sin v \right]_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} = \pi (\sin \frac{\pi}{2} - \sin 0) = \pi (1 - 0) = \pi
$$
The following is the code I have tried in Mathematica 12.0
Clear[DoubleContourIntegral];
DoubleContourIntegral[field_?VectorQ, 
   surface : {changeOfVars : ({x_, y_, z_} -> 
        param : {xuv_, yuv_, zuv_}), {u_, u1_, u2_}, {v_, v1_, 
      v2_}}] := 
  Integrate[(field[[3]] /. Thread[changeOfVars]) Norm[
     Cross[D[param, u], D[param, v]]], {u, u1, u2}, {v, v1, v2}];


Clear[a, b, c];
S = {{x, y, z} -> { Cos[u] Cos[v], 2 Sin[u] Cos[v], Sin[v]}, {u, 
    0, \[Pi]/2}, {v, 0, \[Pi]/2}};
F = {x, y, z};
\[DoubleContourIntegral]F \[DifferentialD]S

This will generate $2/9 (7 EllipticE[3/4] - EllipticK[3/4])$
I also tried to use direct Integrate.
z[x_, y_] := Sqrt[1 - 4 x^2 - y^2];
Integrate[
 x *y*z[x, y]*
  Sqrt[1 + D[z[x, y], x]^2 + D[z[x, y], y]^2], {x, y} \[Element] 
  Disk[{0, 0}, {1, 2}, {0, Pi/2}]]

And this will generate
$$-\frac{13}{540} \biggl(-6 + \sqrt{13} \biggl)$$
-(13/540) (-6 + 13 Sqrt[13])


You have to integrate the dot-product  F.dS (not F3 Norm[dS]) to get the flux
Try
Clear[DoubleContourIntegral];
DoubleContourIntegral[field_?VectorQ, 
   surface : {changeOfVars : ({x_, y_, z_} -> 
        param : {xuv_, yuv_, zuv_}), {u_, u1_, u2_}, {v_, v1_, 
      v2_}}] := 
  Integrate[(field /. Thread[changeOfVars]) . 
    Cross[D[param, u], D[param, v] ], {u, u1, u2}, {v, v1, v2}];


Clear[a, b, c];
S = {{x, y, z} -> {Cos[u] Cos[v], 2 Sin[u] Cos[v], Sin[v]}, {u, 
    0, \[Pi]/2}, {v, 0, \[Pi]/2}};
F = {x, y, z};
\[DoubleContourIntegral]F \[DifferentialD]S  (* Pi *)

alternative
r = {Cos[u] Cos[v], 2 Sin[u] Cos[v], Sin[v]};
dS = Cross[D[r, u], D[r, v]] // Simplify;
Integrate[r . dS , {u, 0, Pi/2}, {v, 0, Pi/2}] (* Pi *)


How abput this direct Integrate
z[x_, y_] := Sqrt[1 - 4 x^2 - y^2]; Integrate[  x *y*z[x, y]*   Sqrt[1 + D[z[x, y], x]^2 + D[z[x, y], y]^2], {x, y} \[Element]    Disk[{0, 0}, {1, 2}, {0, Pi/2}]]

A gave a direct alternative in my answer

A version without the conversions:
Z = Sqrt[1 - x^2 - y^2/4];
y2 = SolveValues[Z == 0, y][[2]]
2 Sqrt[1 - x^2]

reg = ParametricRegion[{x, y, Z}, {x, {y, 0, y2}}];
RegionBounds@reg
{{-1, 1}, {0, 2}, {0, 1}}

Φ = {x, y, Z};
n = D[Φ, x]\[Cross]D[Φ, y];
Integrate[{x, y, z} . n /. z -> Z, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, y2}]  
π

Although SurfaceIntegrate is marked as experimental, it can also be used to calculate the flow through the given surface.
reg2 = ParametricRegion[{x, y, Z}, {{x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, y2}}];
SurfaceIntegrate[{x, y, z}, {x, y, z} ∈ reg2]
π

